# I am getting an error while installing npm in vscode terminal

Tags: reactjs

i am getting an error while installing Node package manager in Virtual studio code terminal that when i enter the command npm install or npm i its showing command not found

Answer (score 0):

in order to run a command with "npm", you have to have it installed.

if on linux, run
`sudo apt install nodejs`
`sudo apt install npm`